# C++: Append to front, add to back array of int's

Tags: c++, arrays

I have the following array:

```
int a1[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

I would like to know how can I append any number to the front, and to the back of this array. In JavaScript, there is unshift() and push(). Is there anything like that in C++?

Comment: No, you can't. Use `std::vector` for variable-length array.

Comment: Or use another data structure such as a ``std::deque<>`` etc. If appending and removing at front and back are your dominating operations. Typically you pick the data structure which suits your needs best. There are plenty.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Answers go down there: ↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓↓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike Javascipt arrays, which are all-purposed arrays, C++ gives you few types of consecutive containers.

In your example, you demonstrated the use of *built-in arrays* also known as *C-arrays*. they are basically size-immutable arrays, and other than being a line of bytes which holds up variables value, they have no special features.

For flexible high-level arrays, use either `std::vector`, or the less known-but-really-awsome `std::deque`.

Also, get familiar with `std::array` which is a good subsitute for built-in arrays.

Comment: "usually sit on the stack"? It may be a global variable which won't usually be on the stack.

Comment: @MikeCAT But we don't usually use globals ;)

Comment: of course it can sit everywhere on the memory. it may be even another process' array. at least I only saw them as local variables.

Comment: Members may well be "on the heap". Best to avoid this nonsense about "where an object lives" entirely.

Comment: I removed it, but you keep ignoring the "usually" part. anyway I removed it

Answer (score 2):

In C++, arrays are a kind of *type*, and the array size is part of the type. Therefore, the size of an array object is part of this object's type and not modifiable at runtime.

To manage dynamic collections of objects in C++, you would usually use a *container* class. There are several useful containers included in the standard library; the most important one is `std::vector`, which manages a dynamic, contiguously stored sequence of elements — essentially a resizable array!

A JavaScript array is much closer to a C++ vector (or perhaps to a hash map) than to a C++ array.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but if you like, you can write a simple code to manage it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct int_array
{
    int *ptr;
    int len;

    int_array(int n_args, ...)
    {
        ptr = NULL;
        len = 0;

        va_list ap;
        va_start(ap, n_args);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n_args; i++) {
            push(va_arg(ap, int));
        }
        va_end(ap);
    }

    int operator[](int idx) const
    {
        return ptr[idx];
    }

    void push(int value)
    {
        ptr = (int*)(len ? realloc(ptr, (len + 1)*sizeof(int)) : malloc(sizeof((len + 1))));
        ptr[len++] = value;
    }

    void unshift(int value)
    {
        ptr = (int*)(len ? realloc(ptr, (len+1)*sizeof(int)) : malloc(sizeof(len+1)));
        for (int i = len++; i > 0; i--)
        {
            ptr[i] = ptr[i-1];
        }
        ptr[0] = value;
    }
}IntArray;


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IntArray arr(6/* initial len */, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

    arr.push(7);
    arr.push(8);
    arr.unshift(0);
    arr.unshift(-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.len;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess it has less overhead than using `vector` or `queue`, although it's not significant in most cases. Anyway, it depends on it that you wanna to learn c++ or you need to just use it!